# How to post form data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

At present I have set 4 variables, the values of which are then stored into mysql.  This works fine. However, I don't want to set the values but write a line of code that takes these values from my form (on the same page). I have set the form method to POST and added specialchars to help security. Can someone pretty please show me one or two lines of code so I don't have to write ="John Doe". Please remember that I am very new all of this

```
<?php

// Connect to the Database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "topsecretDontTell";
$dbname = "gaming";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

// Show error if connection fails
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){ 
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() . 
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() .")"
        );
}
?>

<?php
// ordertbl
    $customer_name = "John Doe";
    $game_id = 3;
    $reservation_start = "2015-01-05";
    $requested_days = 1;

// removes single quotes (escapes strings)
    $customer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $customer_name);

//add into ordertbl
    $query  = "INSERT INTO ordertbl (customer_name,game_id,reservation_start,requested_days) VALUES ('{$customer_name}',{$game_id},'{$reservation_start}', {$requested_days})";

//Run query and test if there was a query error  
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed."); 
 }
?>

<?php    
//determine the name of the game via its id using a function    
function GameTitle ($game_id){
$message = "";
if ($gameid ==1){
    $message = "Fantasy World";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==2){
    $message = "Sir Wags A Lot";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==3){
    $message = "Take a Path";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==4){
    $message = "River Clean Up";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==5){
    $message = "PinBall";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==6){
    $message = "Ghost girl";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==7){
    $message = "Dress up";
    }
    else if ($gameid ==8){
    $message = "Where is my hat?";
    }
    else {
    $message = "Invalid ID";
    }
    return $message;
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
<!--Link to the style sheet-->
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<!--Create Header (logo, title and navigation bar)-->
<body>
<div id='main'>
    <div id='titleImage'><img title='Home' src='images/GLLogo.png' width='700' height='190' alt='Games Library Title' /></div>
    <div id='menu-wrapper'>
        <div id='menu'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='current_page_item'><a href='#'>Reservations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--Make the form-->
    <div class="form">
    <h1>Reservations</h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
      <table width="755" border="3" cellpadding="6">

        <tr>
          <td width="195" align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><label for="customer_name">Name:</label></td>
          <td width="370"><input name="customer_name" autofocus type="text" id="customer_name" size="35" maxlength="90" required autocomplete="off" /></td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><label for="game_id">Game's ID:</label></td>
          <td><input name="game_id" type="number" id="game_id" size="35" maxlength="50" min="1" /></td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="195" align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><button onClick="GameTitle(); return false">Search</button></td>
          <td><input name="Result" type="text" id="demo" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><label for="Loan">Number of Days you wish to borrow the Game</label></td>
          <td><select name="requested_days" id="requested_days">
            <option selected="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr> <!--put date into value field to get a calendar-->
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><label for="reservation">Reservation Date:</label></td>
          <td><input id="reservation_start" input name="reservation_start" type="" value="" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" title="The date should be in the exact format: YYYY-MM-DD with leading zeros where necessary"/> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><label for="mysearch2">Enter your search string here : </label></td>
          <td><input {background-colour: #E5F5EF;} id="mysearch2" type="search" placeholder="search"size="35" maxlength="50"/>
        </tr>   

         <tr>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FF0000"><input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset Form" /></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Submit Form" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
// get rid of data in cache and close
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: `$customer_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['customer']);` there. For even John O'Reilly or John Doe'ish or "Wish I'd had a customer name". Unless I went off on a complete tangent.

Comment: Hard to give you a definite answer; you didn't post your HTML form, nor do I even know if your form is POST/GET, or even holds name attributes.

Comment: Tangent @Fred-ii- ? You? ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah Jay. I've got competition down below and not "down under", unless you're an Aussie and don't want to really say if ye are or not. Like, 15 points / 10 give OR take is going to kill me.

Comment: I wasn't far off `$customer_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['customer_name']);`

Comment: You also haven't assigned anything to `$gameid` - you have `function GameTitle ($game_id)` maybe you meant `function GameTitle ($gameid)`

Comment: You're also trying to call a PHP function with a JS method; that won't work.

Comment: @Fred -ii Ah..thank you!!!!! I've been sat here since 6.00pm trying to do this. Pass the champaign! What is the purpose of $con?

Comment: You're welcome, so problem solved? `$con` was an example since I didn't know what your variable was to connect with. The `$connection` is required when using `mysqli_` functions that need a parameter be passed.

Comment: ...and shall I make that an answer so we can wrap it all up? Seeing I've done 99.9% of the work ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii Yes, I can apply the code to other variables to add other values to my database.  It's a massive help! You are correct about the game id. I wrote the IF statement and wrapped it up in a function, however, I have not managed to use the function so that when I hit my search button it shows the name of the game.  I can do this in Java but not php.

Comment: @ Fred -ii Yes please make it your answer and I'll vote. It was well worth the flack and the loss of reputation popints

Comment: It has been done Rick, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following, taking the POST variable from your form's `<input name="customer_name"...` element:

```
$customer_name=stripslashes($_POST['customer_name']);
$customer_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['customer_name']);
```

which will allow for names containing apostrophes like John O'Reilly.

Plus, you have `function GameTitle ($game_id)` therefore you most likely meant to use `function GameTitle ($gameid)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_POST. In that array are post data. For example:

```
$customer_name = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: What about sanitizing this? If it's worth doing right, it's worth doing right the first time. Of course you'll have to assume whether the OP is using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I guess rubber gloves didn't come as an option, nor Ajax or Comet bleach. You remember Ajax right? The original?

Comment: No @Fred-ii-, but you could be creative in your function naming.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Creative; I can be that. Could come up with some real swanky code.

Comment: @Rasclatt That and maybe a shot of Jay's 20 year old Scotch. Hoping he's going to want to share a shot; or two.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll share, I'll share!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll bring the 7 year old cheddar then. Maybe even dinner rolls, but you'll have to furnish the olives; I ate all of mine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have added my full script, There are one or two problems (my IF regarding game choice is not working) and database shows redundancy (customer name). Please remember I really am trying hard to learn. I only picked  up html 2 weeks ago and php 1 week ago. Ditto mysql

Comment: @RickTicky [Here is your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203062/how-to-post-form-data-in-mysql#comment44772984_28203062) partly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *The plot thickens*. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28203062/revisions - I think I'm ready for that shot now.